# Vanilla JS Swipe Function Now Overrides Links/Expected Behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have written a detect swipe left or right script; it has one unintended consequence. Links that reside within the swipeable container are no longer clickable.

I was wondering if anyone had any solutions they could point me to or any thoughts to experiment with my code.

I have tried:

- Adding/toggling with `event.preventDefault()` within the Pointer Events
- Looking at other get gesture type scripts, they include a distance threshold. If it is does not meet the threshold, I remove all event listeners. Adding this creates an unexpected result of working, only if you click the button twice.
- Find the clickable elements within the container such as a `span a` , add an incremental click event listener then change the `window location ref`. Kinda works, but when you swipe near the span; the selection takes over and swipe actions stop. Experimenting with css `touch-action: none` or `user-select:none` have not improved the experience. It feels like I am breaking the default behaviour and reinventing the wheel.

[link to a demo here on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/xuhaxugopa/edit?html,console,output)

JS code here

```
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let test = new getSwipeX({
    elementId: 'container'
  });
  // previous attempt - adding a click on top of the browser default
  let grabBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
    grabBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      window.location.href = 'www.google.co.uk'
    });
  })
  function getSwipeX({elementId}) {

  this.e               = document.getElementsByClassName(elementId)[0];
  this.initialPosition = 0;
  this.lastPosition    = 0;
  this.threshold       = 200;
  this.diffInPosition  = null;
  this.diffVsThreshold = null;
  this.gestureState    = 0;

  this.getTouchStart = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (window.PointerEvent) {
      this.e.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
    }
    return this.initalTouchPos = this.getGesturePoint(event);
  }

  this.getTouchMove  = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return this.lastPosition = this.getGesturePoint(event);
  }

  this.getTouchEnd   = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (window.PointerEvent) {
      this.e.releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
    }
    this.doSomething();
    this.initialPosition = 0;
  }

  this.getGesturePoint = (event) => {
    this.point = event.pageX
    return this.point;
  }

  this.whatGestureDirection = (event) => {
    this.diffInPosition  = this.initalTouchPos - this.lastPosition;
    this.diffVsThreshold = Math.abs(this.diffInPosition) > this.threshold;
    (Math.sign(this.diffInPosition) > 0) ? this.gestureState = 'L' : (Math.sign(this.diffInPosition) < 0) ? this.gestureState = 'R' : this.gestureState = 'N';
    
    return [this.diffInPosition, this.diffVsThreshold, this.gestureState];
  }

  this.doSomething = (event) => {
    let [gestureDelta,gestureThreshold,gestureDirection] = this.whatGestureDirection();

    // USE THIS TO DEBUG
    console.log(gestureDelta,gestureThreshold,gestureDirection);

    if (gestureThreshold) {
      (gestureDirection == 'L') ? console.log('Left') : console.log('Right');
    }  else {
      this.e.removeEventListener('pointerdown', this.getTouchStart, true);
      this.e.removeEventListener('pointermove', this.getTouchMove, true);
      this.e.removeEventListener('pointerup', this.getTouchEnd, true);
      this.e.removeEventListener('pointercancel', this.getTouchEnd, true);
    }
  }

  if (window.PointerEvent) {
    this.e.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.getTouchStart, true);
    this.e.addEventListener('pointermove', this.getTouchMove, true);
    this.e.addEventListener('pointerup', this.getTouchEnd, true);
    this.e.addEventListener('pointercancel', this.getTouchEnd, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty certain that the `stopPropagation()`/`preventDefault()` calls are the cause of this problem

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your message. I've removed both ```stopPropagation()``` and ```preventDefault()``` of them (locally) and unless I have done it wrong; the button is still not clickable